# jQuery Validation - Using EqualTo with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin for my form, and I would like to use the EqualTo rule to ensure that the input of checkbox A is the same as checkbox B.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="A" name="A" type="checkbox"/> A<br />
        <input id="B" name="B" type="checkbox"/> B<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            A: {
                equalTo: "#B"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't work as I intended. Instead, it submits if A is checked and blocks submission if A is not checked (validation did not depend on B at all!)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `equalTo` method is typically for comparing the **values** of two *text* elements.  It's not really meant for checkboxes; but even so, your checkboxes are missing `value` attributes.

If I add `value` attributes, it still does not work properly because when the checkbox is not checked, there is no `value` to compare and the `equalTo` rule is ignored.  In other words, both checkboxes would need to already be checked in order for the `equalTo` rule to compare anything, and in that case, it's pointless.

---

Using the `equalTo` rule implies that you want validation to pass when both are checked and pass when both are un-checked.

In order to do this, you would make the `required` rule conditional; it depends on the state of something else.  `A` is only required when `B` is checked and vice-versa.  If nothing is checked, nothing is required, so validation passes.

In this example, both checkboxes must be "equal".  Both checked or both unchecked for validation to pass.

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        A: {
            required: function() {
                return $('#B').is(':checked');
            }
        },
        B: {
            required: function() {
                return $('#A').is(':checked');
            }
        }
    }, ....
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/xdxL9ewp/](https://jsfiddle.net/xdxL9ewp/)**

Comment: This achieves exactly what I wanted. I appreciate both the conceptual explanation and the code example. Thank you.